# Change text characters

Tags: vb6

i want to replace the alphabets with numbers from a text box and display in the result in another test box.Do not know how to achieve this.Please help.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
txtID.Text = "a s d f"
txtSerial.Text = txtID.Text
End Sub

Private Sub cmdGet_Click()
Dim i as Integer
fsID = UCase(Replace(txtID.Text, " ", ""))   ' Remove all spaces '
For i = 1 To Len(fsID) 
ch = Mid(fsID, i, 1)        
               '    Decoder                        '
Next                                 
End Sub

Private Sub Decoder()
Select Case ch
    Case "A"
        txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtID.Text, "A", "0")
    Case "B"
        txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtID.Text, "B", "1")
    Case "H"
        txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtID.Text, "H", "2")
    Case "E"
        txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtID.Text, "E", "3")
    Case "M"
        txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtID.Text, "M", "4")
    Case "N"
        txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtID.Text, "N", "5")
    Case "T"
        txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtID.Text, "T", "6")
    Case "I"
        txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtID.Text, "I", "7")
    Case "P"
        txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtID.Text, "P", "8")
    Case "R"
        txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtID.Text, "R", "9")
    End Select

   End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you want.  Does this do the trick?

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    txtID.Text = "a s d f"
    txtSerial.Text = txtID.Text
End Sub

Private Sub cmdGet_Click()
    txtSerial.Text = UCase(txtID.Text)
    txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtSerial.Text, "A", "0")
    txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtSerial.Text, "B", "1")
    txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtSerial.Text, "H", "2")
    txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtSerial.Text, "E", "3")
    txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtSerial.Text, "M", "4")
    txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtSerial.Text, "N", "5")
    txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtSerial.Text, "T", "6")
    txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtSerial.Text, "I", "7")
    txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtSerial.Text, "P", "8")
    txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtSerial.Text, "R", "9")
    txtSerial.Text = Replace(txtSerial.Text, " ", "")
End Sub
```

Comment: works perfect.Its like a code generator.Depending on what alphabet is inputed I get the corresponding number.example abe will give 013.Thank you very much.